# Laravel - Populate select optgroup dropdown which groups records by name

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-4

I am trying to populate a `select` dropdown in Laravel to show attributes for products.

```
<select>
  @foreach($attributes as $key=>$attr)    
  <optgroup label="{{$attr->name}}">
    <option value="{{$attr->value}}">{{$attr->value}}</option>
  </optgroup>
  @endforeach
</select>
```

When the user stores data for the attributes he may store `Color: Red with id=1` and `Color: Blue with id=2`.

The query used to get the data is:

```
$attributes = Attribute::orderBy('name', 'ASC')->get();
```

Although, I need to find similar records based on their names, like for example the `Color`.  The `select` dropdown should be listing `$attr->name` once in the `<optgroup label>` while the `$attr->value` should be repeated in the `<option value>`.

I have tried to alter the query and use `groupBy` but this won't work as is expected. The query will return just the first instance of any record the rest are ignored.

```
$attributes = Attribute::orderBy('name', 'ASC')->groupBy('name')->get();
```

*How can I solve this? Thank you in advance.*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would put all of the attributes into a multi-dimensional array, and then iterate to produce the select.

```
// Fetch all attributes
$results = Attribute::orderBy('name', 'ASC')->get();
$attributes = array();
/**
 *  Group results into a multidimensional array like:
 *  [color]
 *      [red]
 *      [white]
 *  [shape]
 *      [circle]
 *      [square]
 */
foreach ( $results as $v ) {
    if ( !isset($attributes[$v->name]) ) {
        $attributes[$v->name] = array();
    }
    $attributes[$v->name][$v->value] = $v->value;
}
// Spit out the select/option groups
?>
<select>
      @foreach ( $attributes as $key => $attr )    
      <optgroup label="{{$key}}">
        @foreach ( $attr as $values )
            <option value="{{$value}}">{{$value}}</option>
        @endforeach
      </optgroup>
      @endforeach
</select>
```